# css: min-width and min-height not working for span?

Tags: html, css, size

I'm trying to force a `<span>` section to a certain width and height. As far as I understand, css `min-width` and `min-height` are supposed to take care of this.

However it doesn't work: [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/2pv4z8sd/)

I've also tried adding css properties like `height:100%` or `min-height:100%` for `body` and/or `html` and/or the `<span>` tag, as suggested in other answers to similar questions, or using `<div`> instead of `<span>`, or using `display:block` or `display:inline-block`, but none of that seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Works just fine with inline-block https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/jf4nhL38/

Comment: @WaldirBolanos well I'll be damned. I'd swear I tried that. Maybe I made a typo. Works fine now, thanks 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `display:inline-block` or `display:block` for span. Because `span`'s has `display:inline` as default. Can't set `height` or `width` for `inline` elements.

```css
#test {
  display:inline-block;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fa0;
}
```

```html
<span id='test'>Hello</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use height and width for inline elements.
Use div instead of span tag or use span tag within div element.